# How many approval requests did we send last quarter?

Tags: approval-process

Using Apttus Approvals, I need to find out how many approval requests we sent out last quarter - and the ration of approvals to rejections. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

John

Comment: 1. Do you mean the total number of approval requests sent out for the custom object (quote/agreement etc.). I am asking this coz depending upon how the approval processes are setup in your org each submission could result in multiple approval requests. For ex: if there are 10 quotes in the system and 6 of them went out to sales manager, sales vp and vp then do you expect the total of 6 or 6x3(for each of the approval requests) = 18? 2. It would also be great if you could give a similar elaborated example for the ratio of approvals to rejections.

Comment: I mean the actual number of approval requests that went out - 6 x 3 - and of these, how can I track which ones were approved and which ones were rejected? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can query the approval request object to get the statistics that you are looking for. Note that we have excluded the approval requests records which are created for system use only (status ==none)

**Total Number of Approvals Sent in Last Quarter (you may modify the date condition as per your requirement)**

```
select count(id),  Apttus_Approval__Object_Id__c from Apttus_Approval__Approval_Request__c where Apttus_Approval__Approval_Status__c !='None' and CreatedDate > LAST_QUARTER group by Apttus_Approval__Object_Id__c
```

**Total Number of approvals by approval status:**

```
select count(id),  Apttus_Approval__Object_Id__c, Apttus_Approval__Approval_Status__c from Apttus_Approval__Approval_Request__c where Apttus_Approval__Approval_Status__c !='None' and CreatedDate > LAST_QUARTER group by Apttus_Approval__Object_Id__c,Apttus_Approval__Approval_Status__c
```

Hope this helps.